# How to read values from a specific column in python?

Tags: python

For instance, I would like to know if the specified column in a .csv file contains ten consecutive 1's.

**My Code:**

```
f = open('file.csv', "r")
readCSV = csv.reader('file.csv',delimiter= ",")

i = 10
while i > 0:
    for row in readCSV :
        if readCSV.index_col('Output').Contains('1'):
            print('works')
        else:
            pass
i = i-1
```

**Error:**

> AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'index_col'

Comment: Make that `if row.index_col(...`

Comment: Your question seems unrelated to pandas

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state whether you're looking for ten consecutive 1's or (as I assume) the total amount.
If you're testing for the number of occurencies, you could use a simple "count":

```
a="15983851284931148960382"

b=a.count('1')

print "amoutn of 1's: " + str(b)
```

If you search for a string of ten 1's you can construct a re pattern and match for it:

```
import re
a="15983851284931148960382"
m = re.search("1111111111",a)
if a:
   print("found:", m)
```

Comment: Yes, it is 10 consecutive 1's and it works the way you've mentioned, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The f variable should be passed as the argument in csv.reader() method not the actual file itself.

Your code should be:

f = open('file.csv', "r")

readCSV = csv.reader('f',delimiter= ",")